# Why is the SvgIcon is not rendering in React MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-ui

*I am trying to create a custom SVG component with material UI and typescript in rect that can be reused as an icon anywhere.
But, the icon is not rendering in the screen. I can't figure out why?*

```
import { SvgIcon, SvgIconProps } from "@mui/material";

const ImgCompress: React.FunctionComponent<SvgIconProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <SvgIcon
            viewBox="0 0 512.000000 512.000000"
            width="512.000000pt"
            height="512.00000pt"
            transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
            stroke="none"
            fill="#000000"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
        >
            <path d="M15,19.16V15.07a4.27,4.27,0,0,0,6,0h0a4.27,4.27,0,0,0,0-6h0a4.27,4.27,0,0,0-6,0l-3,3-3,3a4.27,4.27,0,0,1-6,0h0a4.27,4.27,0,0,1,0-6h0A4.27,4.27,0,0,1,9,9" />
        </SvgIcon>
    );
};

export default ImgCompress;
```

Comment: **1**. the transformation you are using is throwing the svg element below the fold. If you scroll down you may find a very small svg. **2**. inside a viewBox 512/512 you have a minuscul icon of not even 25/25 probably invisible in the scaled down svg element

Comment: @enxaneta what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: What do you need to achieve? I **suppose** you may want to turn the icon upside down. In this case you need to apply the transformation to the icon not to the svg element. If this is the case you don't need to scale it down. Svg stands for _scalable vector graphics_. Just use a proper viewBox attribute